# How can a protected pure virtual function in the base class be used by a friend class of the base class?

Tags: c++, oop

I have an abstract base class

```
class Base {
friend class Friend;
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
protected:
    virtual void eval() = 0;

};

class Derived: public Base {
public:
     Derived = default;
protected:
     virtual void eval() { // implementation of eval()}
};
```

Note that class Friend is the friend of Base, not Derived. My question is:
Can Friend call eval() by using the pointer to Base? For example,

```
void Friend::foo() {
    shared_ptr<Base> bpt(new Derived);
    bpt->eval()
}
```

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: you have a typo in code:  `Derived() = default;`

Answer (score 0):

Access to class members is determined based on static type, not on dynamic one. Static type of pointer is `Base*` and `Friend` got access to `eval()` in vtable of `Base`, but call is routed to a member function of dynamic type.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is very helpful!